# How to use micro cloud foundry vm image on a NONE intel-vt machine

Tags: vmware, cloud-foundry

My notebook: HP CQ40(intel i3 processor) , windows 7 64bit.
When run micro cloud foundry in vmare workstation 9 on my system, I will get an error like "need intel vt support", I read the VMWARE official document about "intel vt",  but I can not find the option in my BIOS, and search this in HP forum, and found that it dose not support intel vt.

How to use Micro cloud foundry in my system? Is there a solution to overcome this barrier?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't think there is. Have you tried another 64bit OS in VMWare Workstation?

Comment: Thanks for ur help. Consult the help document from HP, maybe my CPU lacks this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have virtualisation enabled (or possible) on your processor. Without this you can't run 64bit virtual machines. Though 32bit will do fine. So make sure you don't assign  more than 1.2 GB to you vm instance. If possible use a solely 32bit vmware workstation or player.